# Notify AsyncTaskLoader when data source is changed from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new in android and I'm not sure if what I'm looking for possible, is it possible to update the listview content handled by the loader manager from a thread? if yes can you please show me how?

More details are below, I've removed many lines for brevity, please let me know if you need more details

The HandlerThread I'm using is this and where I need to notify the loader about the change to udpate the listview content

```
    public void syncWithBackend(Context context) {
    //Connect to the server over HTTP and get the latest data after receiving 
    //the GCM tickle message then save the result in DB

    dbhelper.saveFm(id, artno, comment );

//Here is where I need to notify the loader or the list about the new change 
// to view the new saved data
     context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);


}
```

The URI I'm using is belwo,

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("sqlite://com.pack.android.and/posts");
```

my LoaderCallbacks is this

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new FeedListCursorLoader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cCursorAdapter adapter = new cCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
            (fCursor) cursor);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    setListAdapter(null);
}
```

My Intent Service is this

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

//Here I got the GCM message, call the thread to sync with the backend

        hanlder1.queueHttp(this);

}
```

My AsyncTaskLoader is this

```
public abstract class SQLiteCursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {
    private Cursor cCursor;

    public SQLiteCursorLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
//I'm overriding this from the Fragment to get the cursor after querying sqlite DB 
    protected abstract Cursor loadCursor();

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = loadCursor();
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.getCount();
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

             }
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(Cursor data) {
        Cursor oldCursor = cCursor;
        cCursor = data;

        if (isStarted()) {
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }

        if (oldCursor != null && oldCursor != data && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
            oldCursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
      ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(Cursor cursor) {
      ...    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
       ...      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not quite as you expect.

You will not update the cursor, you will replace it.  In fact, the `LoaderManager` will do it for you, automatically.  It is almost unbelievably simple

When you create a cursor, in response to the request from your `Loader`, register it as a listener for a particular URI:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

The URI can be anything you want.  It represents (is the "name" of?) the data.

When your `Loader` is run by the `LoaderManager`, the `LoaderManager` gets the cursor that the `Loader` returns, before it hands it to you, in the callback.  **It registers as a listener, on that cursor.**

If, at some point after that, you announce that a change has taken place, in the data that that URI represents, like this:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

The cursor (registered as a listener on that URI) will be notified.  When the cursor is notified, the `LoaderManager` (which registered as a listener on the cursor) will be notified, and it will, **automatically, re-run the Loader!**

In your case, you would do the notification on that other thread...

If your `onLoadFinished` method simply swaps out the old cursor and swaps in the new one, your `ListView` will update by magic.

Some parts of Android are just awesome.

**Edited to add sample code:**

Here is some example code to demonstrate how this works.  `db` is a reference to a `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  The methods `insert` and `query` are simple db insert and query respectively.

First the insert code:

```
db.insert();
getContentResolver().notifyChange(DbHelper.URI, null);
```

Then the Loader:

```
private static class MagicLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {
    private final DbHelper db;
    private volatile Cursor cursor;
    private final ContentObserver obs = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() { return true; }
        @Override public void onChange(boolean selfChange) { onContentChanged(); }
    };

    public MagicLoader(Context ctxt, DbHelper db) {
        super(ctxt);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (null == cursor) { forceLoad(); }
        else { deliverResult(cursor); }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        cursor = db.query();
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                cursor.setNotificationUri(
                    getContext().getContentResolver(),
                    DbHelper.URI);
                cursor.getCount();
                cursor.registerContentObserver(obs);
            }
            catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                cursor.close();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return cursor;
    }
};
```

Note that this would all be a lot easier if you were just using a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm trying to do it like so, I've added cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri); to the  public Cursor loadInBackground(), is that correct?, the second thing is what the URI should be? I'm using sqlite db btw

Comment: It sounds like it might work.  As I said, use whatever URI you want.  3 steps: 1) Choose a URI.  2) Register the the cursor as an observer on that URI.  3) Notify a change on the URI whenever the dataset changes.  4) Profit

Comment: still not working, how can I detect the notification? I'm trying to getting it printed in the log to see if it's getting called.

Comment: I'm doing this btw,             Uri uri = Uri.parse("sqlite://com.pack.android.and/posts");
             context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);                and this to notify             cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

Comment: Try a uri that begins with "content://".  I've never tried one that begins "sqlite://" come to think of it.

Comment: I updated the question to show where exactly I'm using what you've suggested.

Comment: That actually looks like it ought to work.  Let me try it.  I'll be right back.

Comment: Thanks, so do you think it's better if I my own ContentProvider?

Comment: Yes!  Use a ContentProvider!